# Choosing which image shows when you use Facebook's Send button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, social-networking, facebook-social-plugins

I'm trying to add a Like and Send button to me site, but when I click 'send' it randomly picks an image. I've even deleted that image as well as changed that image to the image I want, but it's still displaying the wrong image.

Is there anyway I can choose which image is shown there? I've tried adding the Open Graph Tags to the  tag, but again it's still showing the wrong image.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change it with the open graph tags, but unless you reset the cache on FB's side, it will continue to use the same image as it did.

> Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are
>   up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph
>   page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered into the
>   Facebook URL Linter. Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs - it
>   will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of preference.
>   However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your
>   page every 24 hours.

[Facebook URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/)

Comment: Thank you that sounds exactly what I want to do - is it possible to reset the cache myself or do I have to wait?

Comment: Enter the url of the page to the url linter tool at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Comment: FB Lint shows everything correct, however, old image is still presented. I'll wait 24 hrs...